# Showing a subview temporary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

What I am trying to achieve is showing a view during a couple of seconds without user intervention. Is the same effect as the ringer volume view that appears when pressing the volume controls on iphone:

[image: ringer]

I have a scroll view with an image, taping in the image, sound begin to play, another tap and it pauses. I would like to implement the above effect just to inform of the action (showing a play/pause images).

I hope that I have explained the problem perfectly.

Many thanks for your help.

Regards
Javi

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? You'll find that many people here won't help you unless you've tried it yourself first.

Comment: you can make a UIView visible/unvisible with the alpha property set to 1/0

Comment: first post you code than we can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have some class inherited from `UIViewController`. You can use the code below:

```
const int myViewTag = 10001;
const int myInterval = 1; // define the time you want your view to be visible

- (void)someAction {
    //this could be your `IBAction` implementation
    [self showMyView];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:myInterval
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(hideMyView)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}


- (void) showMyView {
    //you can also use here a view that was declared as instance var
    UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 120, 120)] autorelease];

    myView.tag = myViewTag;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}

- (void) hideMyView {
    //this is a selector that called automatically after time interval finished
    [[self.view viewWithTag:myViewTag] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

You can also add some animations here but this is another question :)

Comment: @Black Frog, Don't worry, I've just rejected it

Comment: Thanks @NR4TR, this is what I was trying to achieve